# Reading dynamic allocated vectors from binary file

Tags: file, file-io, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I need help reading two dinamic allocated vectors from a binary file.
There is a Segmentation Fault error eventually, but the vectors remain full of zeros ( sometimes w/ zeros and "garbage") even when the fread() is done without problems.

Here's the code that I use to read it:

```
struct Node *node;  
node = (Node *) calloc(GRAPHSIZE,sizeof(Node));

int edgesSize = 2*GRAPHSIZE;

int *edges;
edges = (int *) calloc(edgesSize,sizeof(int));  

FILE * file;

printf("\nLoading graph file...\n");

file = fopen ("graph1M.g","rb");    
fread (&edges, edgesSize * sizeof(int),1,file);
fread (&node, GRAPHSIZE * sizeof(Node),1,file);
fclose(file);
```

And that's how they are being saved:

```
int edgesSize = 2*GRAPHSIZE;

struct Node *node;  
node = (Node *) calloc(GRAPHSIZE,sizeof(Node));


int *Edges;
Edges = (int *) calloc(edgesSize,sizeof(int));  


/* put data into the vectors... */


FILE *file;

//writes file:
file = fopen ("graph1M.g","wb");
fwrite (&Edges, edgesSize * sizeof(int),1,file);
fwrite (&node, GRAPHSIZE * sizeof(struct Node),1,file);
fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are buggy (you are corrupting your stack):

```
fread (&edges, edgesSize * sizeof(int),1,file);
fread (&node, GRAPHSIZE * sizeof(Node),1,file);
```

You want this instead:

```
fread (edges, edgesSize * sizeof(int),1,file);
fread (node, GRAPHSIZE * sizeof(Node),1,file);
```

Same problem with `fwrite` as well.

BTW, if you are on Linux, you should test your programs with Valgrind. Do that often, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Ty, that solved the problem, also I'll take a look at this Valgrind.